# How to convert LineFeed delimited file to one line using repl.bat

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd

For example:

I have a set of strings:

```
AAAA~
BBBB~
```

Expected:

```
AAAA~BBBB~
```

Im currently using repl.bat as my find and replace tool impelemented in a batch file as follows:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('type c:\user\delim.txt') do (

    copy "C:\user\linefeed\%%a" "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp"
        for /f "tokens=1,*" %%s in (FindNReplace.txt) do (
            Type "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp"  | C:\user\bat\repl.bat "%%s" "%%t" X > "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.out.tmp"
            move /y "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.out.tmp" "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp"
        )
  move "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp" "C:\user\clientout\%%a"
)
```

Example contents of delim.txt

```
^(AAAAA.{5}).{4}(.*)$       $17777$2
```

**^(AAAAA.{5}).{4}(.*)$**   - This will find a pattern that starts with AAAAA followed by any 5 chars and 4 succeeding characters

**$17777$2**   - Match value will be replaced by 7777

What will be the equivalent value in RegEx in order to convert line feed delimited into a single line?

Comment: Not sure I well understand, but how about replacing linefeed by nothing? Ie. : replace `\R` by ``.

Comment: \R is the equivalent in regex?  @M42

Comment: `\R` stands for any line break, `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I think M42 is right:

> how about replacing linefeed by nothing? Ie. : replace \R by ""; \R stands for any line break, \n or \r or \r\n.

If you want only the linefeed character, then do \r only.